# two forms with same name and in between an other form

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>

<form name="UsernameCheck" action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="fakeusername">//it will have been give    username value from javascript
<input type="submit" name="checkUsername" id="checkUsername">
</form>

<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email id="email">
<input type="submit" name="register" id="Register">
```

Do first and third form will be treated by php as one form or they would be treated as different forms.
can i access first form text field by checking isset submit of third form as both first and third form has same name.

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
}
```

Is it possible to access the value? Or if I give same id to both forms, then it could be possible to achieve what I want to?

Comment: What was your conclusion after you tested it?

Comment: you can only submit one form at a time. and form id only used for client side processing, it has no value on the server side

Comment: @PeeHAa :- it was not recognizing fname, for confirmation i wanted to ask as I am new to php

Comment: @DevZer :-I have not used submit in the first form, i am using it in third form only so html or browser doesn't take it as continuation?

Comment: once you close a form </form> its done

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, I think the close votes were unfair as you just needed to reword slightly. What you have are three separate forms - submitting the third one will not magically submit all other forms with the same name.

Comment: @PaulDixon what are close votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be treated as different forms. When you/the user submits the first form , it will send the form data from the first form, if the second one gets submitted it will send the data from the second form. The `name="register"` has no actual influence.

Your first formular has no submit button, so it's data will never get send. The webbrowser sends the data from the formular where the clicked submit button is inside.

If you have multiple forms with the same url (`action=""`) specified, you should use an hidden input to determine which formular got submitted. You can also set just different names on the submit button, as these will get sent to the server, too, like that:

```
<form action="bla.php">
<input name="some_data" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit form 1" name="submit_1">
</form>

<form action="bla.php">
<input name="some_data" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit form 2" name="submit_2">
</form>
```

And then you can query it in php via:

```
if (isset($_GET['some_data'])) {
  $form_selected = isset($_GET['submit_1'] ? 1 : 2);
}
```

Comment: :- yeah i tried with different name on submit button and I got successful. I wanted to implement the above one for less complex coding.Thanks :)

Comment: I've added a code sample

Answer (score 1):

Each of those forms is completely separate. The "name" of the form has no effect. The first and third form in your example would be submitted completely separate from each other, not together.

If you need to have multiple forms on the same page, and determine which one was posted, use a hidden field to track them.

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form 1">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```

In PHP just check if `$_POST[ 'action' ] == 'form 1'`. Each form can have a different action name.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute itself is outdated for `form` elements (but not for form fields, where it keeps being essential). [The HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM) clause on `form` says:

“`name` = cdata [CI] This attribute names the element so that it may be referred to from style sheets or scripts. Note. This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the id attribute to identify elements.”

In the HTML5 drafts, even the formal rules disallow the use of the same name attribute. The HTML5 clause on the name attribute on `form` says that its value “must be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection that it is in, if any”. This is a confusing formulation, but it is safest to assume that it must be unique within the form elements of a document.